# Segmentation fault when reading arguments from command line

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a duplicate cat function in c. I am getting segmentation faults, and I am unable to find why.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>




int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char* s;        /* input string */

    int c;

    if(argc==1){


        while (gets(s)){
            puts(s);
        }
    }

    else{

    FILE *file = fopen( "./argv[1]", "r" );
    while((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
        fputc(c,stdout);

    }

    fclose(file);   

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should debug your program. If you don't know how to do that this is a perfect time learn. This will almost always give you the line of the error immediately and thus save you from long searches. Second, you never allocated memory for s. And last, you want to open `./argv[1]`, not `"./argv[1]"`.

Comment: Ah yes the daily I-write-stuff-to-an-address-where-nothing-is-allocated question came early today. Too localized, vote to close.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I'm afraid there are yet more of this question in today's daily routine on SO... -.-

Comment: I'd use `fread` instead of `fgets`, as `cat` does not actually need to work using newlines, and that way we avoid special handling for long lines.

Answer (score 5):

You are reading characters into `s` without allocating memory:

```
    while (gets(s)){
        puts(s);
    }
```

Allocate some memory first by using `malloc` (you will have to `free` it later):

```
    char *s = malloc(some_buffer_size);
```

or make it fixed:

```
    char s[some_buffer_size];
```

Be careful with `gets` by the way, as there is no way of limiting the number of characters input, which can lead to buffer overflows. Use `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)` instead.

Second mistake has been pointed out by others, you cannot call `fopen` like that, use this instead, or use the solution from H2CO3:

```
 FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
```

Comment: Also `fopen( "./argv[1]", "r" );` note the first argument

Comment: Please [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanx. But now I am getting segmentation faul when trying to read from file

Comment: Using `gets` in the first place is probably more severe a fault than casting the result of `malloc`. `gets` is not part of the C language no longer, don't use it.

Comment: @Fazlan Because your `fopen()` returns `NULL`. Time to read a C book and to develop some common sense.

Comment: No reason not to use a fixed buffer `char s[some_buffer_size]`.

Comment: @Keith That's exactly what was going to be my second comment.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's what I suggest

Comment: @BartFriederichs Yap, didn't see the `f`... Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`gets(s);` - Here `s` is not initialized to point to anything.
`fopen( "./argv[1]", "r" );` - This is wrong. Must be - `fopen(argv[1], "r" );`

Answer (score 0):

```
fopen( "./argv[1]", "r" );
```

Huh, what? Assumptions, right?

```
char buf[0x1000];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "./%s", argv[1]);
FILE *f = fopen(buf, "r");
```

Also, you are using the `s` pointer uninitialized (you don't allocate any memory for it), so your program also invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` basically allocates memory. in the end, you need to `free()` your variable as well to free the allocated space.

you should use `gdb()` for finding out errors and debugging your program.